# How to expand table view cell and show content beneath it?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, expand, custom-cell

I want to have the table view cell expand and show the buttons that I have laid out below the visible view when the cell isn't selected. So far I have managed to expand the cell so that the entire view shows with the buttons, but there is one major problem with this....

The buttons that are supposed to be revealed only when the cell is selected always appear in the table, and the table view looks really weird becuase for each cell there are buttons overlapping the next cell which were supposed to be hidden!

I have tired making a subclass of the cell, but I am stuck because when I override the setSelected method to show the button, all the buttons from all the cells show up, not just the one I clicked, Ill provide my code below.

I there an easier way to show the buttons without using a subclass? And if not how could I use the subclass in a way that wouldn't show all the buttons for all the cells?

Cell Subclass (.m file)

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
editHidden.hidden = YES;
removeHidden.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

editHidden.hidden = NO;
removeHidden.hidden = NO;
// Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table view delegate needs to implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Implement this method to return the correct height for your cell given the state that it is in (collapsed or expanded).  When it comes time to expand your cell you should update your state and call `[tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates];` to have it recalculate and relayout the tableview.

Comment: I actually have that method, but the problem isn't getting that to work its getting that to show and hide the buttons as it does that. Currently, the buttons show all the time and aren't hidden below the cell view. I can't actually hide the buttons as I can't make it a property with getting an error, so I tried to make a custom cell subclass, but that where I have my problem as described above